# Testcafe - Selecting checkbox using id always end up with the full timeout wait

Tags: testing, iframe, checkbox, selector, testcafe

Our html codes for checkbox always look something  like this

`<div id="paymentCheckBoxesMod" class="c-form__checkbox-container u-spacing__margin-bottom--16 u-spacing__margin-top--16">
<input type="checkbox" id="supplementaryAgreement" aria-describedby="paymentsCheckboxLabel">
<label for="supplementaryAgreement">
</label>`
`<div id="paymentsCheckboxLabel">
Jag godkänner Storytels <span id="purchasetermspopup">Köpvillkor</span> & <span id="privacypolicypopup">Integritetspolicy</span>
</div>
</div>`

ive always located the element using the label's `for="supplementaryAgreement"` because if i use the input's `id="supplementaryAgreement"`i end up having to wait for the timeout duration before the element is located. Does anyone know why?

so that has worked fine until i have to work for iframes and although ive already switched back to mainframe however i will get the error that there is no match on the DOM tree if i use `for="supplementaryAgreement"` now. It still work with `id="supplementaryAgreement"` but having to wait for it to timeout doesn't seem efficient.

Comment: This behavior sounds odd. Do you have a public URL to access it and diagnose the issue? Or, you can provide a small sample application where we can reproduce the issue and examine what's going on.

Comment: yes you can go to Create Account page `https://www.storytel.com/se/sv/skapa-konto` and after creating an account, you will get to the Payment page where i had issue with the checkbox

meanwhile this worked although i am not sure if it is the right way to do it 
`this.suppAgreementCheckbox = Selector('#checkboxid').with({ timeout: 1 })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the cause of this issue is in the complex markup of your checkbox. It seems that the checkbox is overlapped by the `label::after` element, so TestCafe cannot correctly find the checkbox. The other issue is that `label[for=supplementaryAgreement]` has `height` equal to 0.

Your idea with decreasing the timeout for the selector is a good workaround in this case. It does not work since there is a syntax mistake. Please try the following approach: `Selector('#supplementaryAgreement', { timeout: 1000 })`